# Ogg (theora / vorbis) playback in Firefox 3.6

Tags: firefox, video, html, ogg-theora

I have this html5 code, with a MP4 for Chrome (working), an OGG for Firefox (failing) and the same ogg via a java applet for Internet Explorer (working):

```
<video width="848" height="480"  controls="controls" autoplay="true" >
            <source src="vernissage_cpal_2009.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="vernissage_cpal_2009.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
            <applet code="com.fluendo.player.Cortado.class" archive="http://theora.org/cortado.jar" width="848" height="480">
                <param name="url" value="vernissage_cpal_2009.ogv" /> 
            </applet>
 </video>
```

Firefox display a gray box with a X inside it. The file "vernissage_cpal_2009.ogv" also plays well inside normal media player, like VLC.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, trying to embed ogg audio, where it was playing in FF, but not in chromium.

I found I was missing a tag, type audio/ogg. It now plays.
Here is the code:

```
    <object width="300" height="42">
    <param name="src" value="tonystheme.ogg">
    <param name="type" value="audio/ogg">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="controller" value="true">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
    <embed src="tonystheme.ogg" autostart="true" loop="false" width="300" height="42"
    controller="true" bgcolor="#000000"></embed>
    </object>
```

Granted, this is not working with the new html5 code, but, it did make it so the file would play.

Answer (score -1):

Use "video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis" as your mime type and Firefox will play it back happily.

Comment: Incidentally, Minefield (Firefox 3.7a5pre) will happily play that markup. So, if the ogv file is not working, maybe there is a bug in Firefox that you should register with the example file.

Comment: Firefox 3.6 and 3.7 didn't play it. The OVG is valid and plays in offline players, so it may be a server issue in my case.